# c# web api using auth1.0a with OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth, asp.net-web-api2

I set up JWT token based authentication using the **OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider** a while ago. The provider looks like this:

```
public class OAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{

    // Private properties
    private readonly IAdvancedEncryptionStandardProvider _helper;
    private readonly IUserProvider _userProvider;

    // Optional fields
    private readonly Lazy<IClientService> _clientService;

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="helper"></param>
    public OAuthProvider(IAdvancedEncryptionStandardProvider helper, IUserProvider userProvider, Lazy<IClientService> clientService)
    {
        _helper = helper;
        _userProvider = userProvider;
        _clientService = clientService;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Always validate the client because we are using angular
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext  context)
    {

        // Set up our variables
        var clientId = string.Empty;
        var clientSecret = string.Empty;
        Client client = null;

        // Try to get our credentials if basic authentication has been used
        if (!context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret))
            context.TryGetFormCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret);

        // If we have no client id
        if (context.ClientId == null)
        {
            //Remove the comments from the below line context.SetError, and invalidate context 
            //if you want to force sending clientId/secrects once obtain access tokens. 
            context.Validated();
            //context.SetError("invalid_clientId", "ClientId should be sent.");
            return;
        }

        // Get our client 
        client = await _clientService.Value.GetAsync(context.ClientId);

        // If we have no client, throw an error
        if (client == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_clientId", $"Client '{ context.ClientId }' is not registered in the system.");
            return;
        }

        // Get the application type
        if (client.ApplicationType == ApplicationTypes.NativeConfidential)
        {

            // If we have a client secret
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientSecret))
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_clientId", "Client secret shoud be sent.");
                return;
            }

            if (client.Secret != _helper.Encrypt(clientSecret))
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_clientId", "Client secret is invalid.");
                return;
            }
        }

        // If the client is inactive, throw an error
        if (!client.Active)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_clientId", "Client is inactive.");
            return;
        }

        // Set our allowed origin and token expiration
        context.OwinContext.Set<string>("as:clientAllowedOrigin", client.AllowedOrigin);
        context.OwinContext.Set<string>("as:clientRefreshTokenLifeTime", client.RefreshTokenLifeTime.ToString());

        // Validate our request
        context.Validated();
        return;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Authorize the request
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        // Set our allowed origin
        var allowedOrigin = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:clientAllowedOrigin");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(allowedOrigin))
            allowedOrigin = "*";

        // Add our CORS
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Remove("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });

        // Find user by username first
        var user = await _userProvider.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName);

        // If our user actually exists
        if (user != null)
        {

            // Validate the users credentials
            var validCredentials = await _userProvider.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
            var lockoutEnabled = await _userProvider.GetLockoutEnabledAsync(user.Id);

            // If lockout is enabled
            if (lockoutEnabled)
            {

                // If the user entered invalid credentials
                if (validCredentials == null)
                {

                    // Record the failure which also may cause the user to be locked out
                    await _userProvider.AccessFailedAsync(user);

                    // Find out how many attempts are left
                    var accessFailedCount = await _userProvider.GetAccessFailedCountAsync(user.Id);
                    var attemptsLeft = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout"].ToString()) - accessFailedCount;

                    // Inform the user of the error
                    context.SetError("invalid_grant", string.Format(Resources.PasswordInvalid, attemptsLeft));
                    return;
                }

                // Check to see if the user is already locked out
                var lockedOut = await _userProvider.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id);

                // If the user is lockted out
                if (lockedOut)
                {

                    // Inform the user
                    context.SetError("invalid_grant", string.Format(Resources.UserLocked, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan"].ToString()));
                    return;
                }

                // If we get this far, reset the access attempts
                await _userProvider.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(validCredentials);
            }

            // If the user entered the correct details
            if (validCredentials != null)
            {

                // If the user has not confirmed their account
                if (!validCredentials.EmailConfirmed)
                {

                    // Inform the user
                    context.SetError("invalid_grant", Resources.UserHasNotConfirmed);
                    return;
                }

                // Generate our identity
                var oAuthIdentity = await _userProvider.CreateIdentityAsync(validCredentials, "JWT");
                oAuthIdentity.AddClaims(ExtendedClaimsProvider.GetClaims(validCredentials));

                // Create our properties
                var properties = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"as:client_id", string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.ClientId) ? string.Empty : context.ClientId},
                    {"userName", context.UserName}
                });

                // Create our ticket and authenticate the user
                var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
                context.Validated(ticket);
                return;
            }
        }

        // Failsafe
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", Resources.UserOrPasswordNotFound);
        return;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds additional properties to the response
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The current context</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
            context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Grants a refresh token for the current context
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The current context</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override Task GrantRefreshToken(OAuthGrantRefreshTokenContext context)
    {

        // Get our client ids
        var originalClient = context.Ticket.Properties.Dictionary["as:client_id"];
        var currentClient = context.ClientId;

        // If we are not the same client
        if (originalClient != currentClient)
        {

            // Set the error and exit the function
            context.SetError("invalid_clientId", "Refresh token is issued to a different clientId.");
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        // Change auth ticket for refresh token requests
        var newIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Ticket.Identity);

        newIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("newClaim", "newValue"));

        var newTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(newIdentity, context.Ticket.Properties);
        context.Validated(newTicket);

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```

This has worked well and for the most part is fine. My manager how now asked me to put authentication in for other applications using a **key** and **secret**.
I would like to use the **OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider** to do this, but I cannot find any documentation anywhere of how to go about setting this up.

I have read and found a method which can be override: **GrantCustomExtension** and thought that maybe I could use this to set up the authentication but like I have mentioned, I have no idea how to set it up.

Has anyone had experience with this? If they have, could they help me by providing a code example or giving me a link to a resource that I can read?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "authentication in for other applications" can you explain this a little more what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to step away from Asp.net Identity and use [IdentityServer](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/).

IdentityServer4 is an OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 framework for ASP.NET Core.
and IdentityServer3 is for Asp.Net Classic ( although you can use IdentityServer4 with Asp.net classic )

it's really easy to config and very ongoing project.

it has several features like

1. Authentication as a Service
2. Single Sign-on / Sign-out
3. Access Control for APIs
4. Federation Gateway

and for the most important part, it's free and open source.